# Why is hdf5 slow loading a multi-GB dataset (in scala using java bindings)?

Tags: java, performance, scala, hdf5

I'm using HDFJava to read a large (~4.8GB) dataset from file, and it is taking so long (> 5 minutes) that I kill it. Here's the current code:

```
    val faccess_id = H5.H5Pcreate(H5C.H5P_FILE_ACCESS)
    val fin = H5.H5Fopen(svdin, H5C.H5F_ACC_RDONLY, faccess_id)
    val Udset_id = H5.H5Dopen(fin, "/U", H5C.H5P_DEFAULT)

    val dims : Array[Long] = Array(0,0)
    val maxdims : Array[Long] = Array(0,0)
    val daccess_id = H5.H5Pcreate(H5C.H5P_DATASET_XFER)

    println(s"Current buffer size is ${H5.H5Pget_buffer_size(daccess_id)}")
    H5.H5Pset_buffer_size(daccess_id, (8*1024*1024).toLong)

    var filespace = H5.H5Dget_space(Udset_id)
    H5.H5Sget_simple_extent_dims(filespace, dims, maxdims)
    var offset = Array[Long](0,0)
    var stride = Array[Long](1,1)
    var blocksize = Array[Long](1,1)
    var count = Array[Long](dims(0)/5, dims(1))
    var rawdata = Array.ofDim[Double](count(0).toInt, count(1).toInt)
    var memspace = H5.H5Screate_simple(2, count, count)
    H5.H5Sselect_hyperslab(filespace, H5C.H5S_SELECT_SET, offset, stride, count, blocksize)
    H5.H5Sselect_hyperslab(memspace, H5C.H5S_SELECT_SET, offset, stride, count, blocksize)
    println(s"starting to read a ${count(0)}-by-${count(1)} matrix")
    H5.H5Dread(Udset_id, H5C.H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, memspace, filespace, daccess_id, rawdata)
    println("read in U")
```

If I reduce the number of rows read (viz., count(0)) to say 500, the read finishes in a second or less, so I don't think anything is wrong with the way I'm calling the API. I tried changing the buffer size as shown above, but that doesn't help. What can I do to speed up this read?

Comment: this could be due to chunksize settings of the dataset you are trying to access. If your access pattern doesn't align with your chunksize pattern, reading data can be much slower. You can check the chunksize setting by running h5dump or h5ls command line tools on your dataset.

Comment: Are you sure about this line `H5.H5Sselect_hyperslab(filespace, H5C.H5S_SELECT_SET, offset, stride, count, blocksize)` ? i think you should try without it. The ligne `H5.H5Pset_buffer_size(daccess_id, (8*1024*1024).toLong)` is also not necessary. Check that you have enought available RAM ( launch your application with -Xmx10G for example if you have at least 10GB of ram )

Comment: Thanks Umit and Antoine. I'm not using a chunked dataset. I am using -Xmx10G. I have tried with and without the buffer size setting, doesn't make a difference (I added it in case the slow down was due to too small a buffer--- I think it's 1MB by default). I originally did it without specifying a subset of the data; that's slow, so I switched to this subsetting, but that doesn't help.